# adding wordpress menu location in twig template

Tags: wordpress, twig

Im trying to use twig for wordpress template and I'm having problem with use wp_nav_menu function that wordpress use to add menu location.

```
    {% wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) ) %}
```

and this result in error obviously.

Is there a way to fix this? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

found the solution.

```
    $header  = wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'theme_location' => 'header' ,
        'echo' => false ,
    )) ;
```

this with return the menu and the variable can be printed in twig.